# Numpy savetxt - tab delimited text with formatting

Tags: python, numpy

I want to format tab delimited text so I can easily import it to Excel. The other posts I've seen don't seem to address this specific issue. The documentation suggests I should use the option `delimiter = '\t'`. This seems to work for no format or a single format which gets repeated, but it has no effect when each column has a separate format. What am I missing? I have found a solution by putting `\t` in the format string, but this should not be necessary according to the documentation. Why doesn't the function work as described?

Here is some sample code:

```
   fn = open('b.dat','w')
   fmt0 = '%5.2f'
   fmt1 = '%5.1f'*2 + '%6.3f'*2
   fmt2 = '%5.1f\t'*2 + '%6.3f\t' + '%6.3f'
   b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)/3
   print('savetxt b simple fmt0, tab delimiter',file=fn)
   np.savetxt(fn,b,delimiter='\t',fmt=fmt0)
   print('savetxt b fmt1, tab delimiter has no effect ',file=fn)
   np.savetxt(fn,b,delimiter='\t',fmt=fmt1)
   print('savetxt b fmt2 contains tabs + delimiter',file=fn)
   np.savetxt(fn,b,delimiter='\t',fmt=fmt2)
   print('savetxt b fmt2 contains tabs, no delimiter',file=fn)
   np.savetxt(fn,b,fmt=fmt2)
   fn.close()
```

I don't know how to display the tabs here, but the output from this code is as follows. The output with fmt1 does not have tabs - the delimiter option has no effect.

```
savetxt b simple fmt0, tab delimiter
 0.00    0.33    0.67    1.00
 1.33    1.67    2.00    2.33
 2.67    3.00    3.33    3.67
savetxt b fmt1, tab delimiter has no effect 
  0.0  0.3 0.667 1.000
  1.3  1.7 2.000 2.333
  2.7  3.0 3.333 3.667
savetxt b fmt2 contains tabs + delimiter
  0.0     0.3    0.667   1.000
  1.3     1.7    2.000   2.333
  2.7     3.0    3.333   3.667
savetxt b fmt2 contains tabs, no delimiter
  0.0     0.3    0.667   1.000
  1.3     1.7    2.000   2.333
  2.7     3.0    3.333   3.667
```

Comment: The docs specify 3 cases. `fmt0` is one, `fmt1` and `fmt2` are another.  A third is a list of specifiers.  `delimiter`  (default is ' '), is only used with the first and last.  Roughly it constructs a format with `delimiter.join([fmt]*n)` or `delimiter.join(alist)`.

Comment: The docs clearly states that **multi-format string, e.g. 'Iteration %d -- %10.5f', in which
    case `delimiter` is ignored.**

Comment: I had a feeling it was probably buried somewhere in the documentation, but it was not obvious, at least to me. I thought this observation might be helpful to others.